# Javascript Simple If Else innerHTML == 'something' not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a seemingly simple javascript function I am trying to create that checks the value of an elements innerHTML and spits out a value based on the answer, but for the life of me I can't get it to work and don't get any errors. This function is triggered by onclick events and doesn't need to have window.onload added. Any insight anyone could give me would be much appreciated! Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-9 product-info">
  <p id="planTitle" class="bold m-b-2">20 DAY SUPPLY // 40 CAPSULES // FMF</p>
  <p>Price: <span class="pull-right" id="plan-amount">$79</span></p>
  <p>Tax: <span class="pull-right">Included</span></p>
   <p id="shipping-line">Shipping: <span class="pull-right" id="cart-shipping-cost">$9.99</span></p>
    <p class="hidden">Coupon: <span class="pull-right" id="coupon-code">firstmonthfree20day</span></p>
</div>
```

And my Javascript

```
function updateShippingCost(country_region) {
    var url;

    var kkdk = '';
    var planTitleesd = document.getElementById('planTitle').innerHTML;
    console.log(planTitleesd);
    if (planTitleesd == '10 Day Supply // 20 Capsules // FMF') {
        kkdk = '5.99';
        console.log(kkdk);
    } else if (planTitleesd == '20 Day Supply // 40 Capsules // FMF') {
        kkdk = '9.99';
        console.log(kkdk);
    } else if (planTitleesd == '30 Day Supply // 60 Capsules // FMF') {
        kkdk = '14.99';
        console.log(kkdk);
    }
}
```

Oddly, console.log(planTitleesd) returns a value, such as
"20 DAY SUPPLY // 40 CAPSULES // FMF"
but all the other console.log(kkdk) do not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, what **exactly** does that `console.log(planTitleesd)` return?

Comment: Post your markup as well. Have a look at [mcve].

Comment: `console.log(planTitleesd) returns a value, but all the others do not` this suggests that it doesn't pass any of the `if`s

Comment: Thanks for your help. console.log(planTitleesd) returns "10 Day Supply // 20 Capsules // FMF" or "20 Day Supply // 40 Capsules // FMF" correctly. That is why I don't understand how the value is not passing any of the ifs

Comment: It almost definitely doesn't return exactly that. Please provide your markup as an edit to the question so that you have a *verifiable* example

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I have updated the question

Comment: You are doing a case-sensitive comparison. You've indicated that the resultant value is all caps, while you're comparing it to Title Case. Consider doing a case-insensetive comparison by calling `toLowerCase` on both operands before comparison. Also, please actually post your markup. Troubleshooting code questions *must* contain an MCVE.

Comment: Why dont you use integers instead of such long strings for comparison. You can set a rule for each of the sentences and mark them as 0,1,2.

Comment: @user3826864 Please update your question to include the minimal amount of code to have a functioning example of what is happening.

Comment: Don't you have a newline at the end/beginning of the planTitleesd?

Try to replace console.log(planTitleesd); by console.log('>' + planTitleesd + '<'); and check the output

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the original question with the relevant HTML, sorry about that.

> You are doing a case-sensitive comparison. You've indicated that the resultant value is all caps, while you're comparing it to Title Case. Consider doing a case-insensetive comparison by calling toLowerCase on both operands before comparison. Also, please actually post your markup. Troubleshooting code questions must contain an MCVE. – CollinD 9 mins ago

This was the simple answer to the simple question I was looking for - Thanks CollinD!

Answer (score 0):

Almost for sure you have newline at the beginning/end of planTitleesd.
Try to replace `console.log(planTitleesd);` by `console.log('>' + planTitleesd + '<');` to check that.

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/324aw9zz/1/

You should avoid any spaces/newline between the tag opener/closer and the text itself:

```
<th id=planTitle>lala</th>
```

instead of

```
<th id=planTitle>
    lala
  </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something more along the lines of:
Using .indexOf() to check for one (or multiple) Strings?

```
function updateShippingCost(country_region) {
    var url;

    var kkdk = '';
    var planTitleesd = document.getElementById('planTitle').innerHTML;

    if ( planTitleesd.indexOf('10 Day') > -1 && planTitleesd.indexOf('20 Capsules') > -1 ) {
        kkdk = '5.99';
    } else if (planTitleesd.indexOf('20 Day')) {
        kkdk = '9.99';
    } else if (planTitleesd.indexOf('30 Day')) {
        kkdk = '14.99';
    }
}
```

I also agree that you should remove the case sensitive strings, as, (once again), typos and the like can occur.

Chances are there is just a typo in the value, or perhaps an empty return/newline you may be looking over.
Make sure all Carriage Returns and more are removed from the response.  Seeing as, some items may actually add one that you do not notice.  (Such as an openly tabbed div)

It sounds like this app is a store, something that could get pretty big.  I would suggest is maybe an object that returns back the result you need.

The following a JSFiddle that I feel would simplify your process if you could create a proper JSON object.
https://jsfiddle.net/0sscf798/

```
function updateShippingCost(country_region) {
        var url;
        var kkdk = '';
        var planTitleArr = [];
        var planTitleObj = {};
        var planTitleesd = document.getElementById('planTitle').innerHTML;

        // This would most likely be a JSON response of items from the page/category
        planTitleObj = {
            "10 Day Supply": {
              "20 Capsules": {
                "FMF": 1.23
              }
            },
            "20 Day Supply": {
              "20 Capsules": {
                "FMF": 4.56
              }
            }
          };

      planTitleArr = planTitleesd.split(" // ");
      var price = planTitleObj[planTitleArr[0]][planTitleArr[1]][planTitleArr[2]] || "There is a problem with the price."

      alert("The Price is: " + price);
}
updateShippingCost('');
```